# logging.debug() is printing something different than regular print()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a code to find the factorial,i used the logging module.
after searching the site, i haven't found relative questions .
here is my code

```
def factorial(n):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(asctime)s-%(levelname)s-%(message)s')
    logging.debug('Start of program')
    logging.debug('start of action (%s)'%(n))
    total=1
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        #print(i)
        total *=i
        print(total)
        logging.debug('i is '+str(i)+' total='+str(total))
    logging.debug('End of factorial(%s) '%(n))
    return total
def main():
    print(factorial(5))
    logging.debug('End of program')
if __name__=='__main__':
    import logging
    main()
```

the output of total is not 'what it should be' in the

```
logging.debug('i is '+str(i)+' total='+str(total))
```

here is what i get when i run the code

```
2018-11-21 09:34:56,213-DEBUG-Start of program
2018-11-21 09:34:56,213-DEBUG-start of action (5)
1
2018-11-21 09:34:56,213-DEBUG-i is 1 total=12

2018-11-21 09:34:56,213-DEBUG-i is 2 total=2
6
2018-11-21 09:34:56,213-DEBUG-i is 3 total=6
24
2018-11-21 09:34:56,213-DEBUG-i is 4 total=24
120
2018-11-21 09:34:56,213-DEBUG-i is 5 total=120
2018-11-21 09:34:56,213-DEBUG-End of factorial(5) 
120
2018-11-21 09:34:56,213-DEBUG-End of program
```

The question seems long but it should be quite simple operations.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: It looks correct, except for the line where the IO is [presumably] interleaved so it [reportedly] results in 1<NONEWLINE>2<NEWLINE><NEWLINE> instead of 1<NEWLINE>2<NEWLINE>; same for the line with 120 near the bottom.

Comment: @TobiasWilfert the total is not corret check the first line of output the total should be 1

Comment: @timmy the output is 1 the 2 just doesn't get a new line and moves up to the 1 for some reason resulting in a "12" and an empty next line.

Comment: @user2864740 the problem i am having that each time i run it,the total in the logging.debug(...) is very different.

Comment: @TobiasWilfert after running the same code the total seems to change

Comment: @TobiasWilfert i think the problem is that it is not always going to a new line after execution which results to change the total value.

Comment: I cannot replicate this. Neither of `python`, `python3`, `pypy`, `pypy3`, or `jython` show this behaviour under repeated invocation. Do you use threading somewhere? Is the only thing missing the `import logging` statement?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi import logging is just before main(), the problem seems to be that it is not always jumping to a new line when logging.debug(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess but it looks like you have a race condition within your prints. I actually thought logging takes case of this but to check you can try the following:
remove the print statement and run the program. If the program is correct remove the debug and return the print to check again.

The possible (apparently) race condition is that while the logging.debug didn't finish printing the whole line your code now did the print statement. thats why you have empty lines.

Comment: it does fix it,total is now consistent and correct. i wonder why it was giving those results with the print() on line 9 of code.

Comment: @timmy It is a very classic race condition where the shared resource is the screen (printing stream). To learn more you can look here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software

If the answer helped you please accept it.

Comment: A race condition implies concurrent work. `print` should only return after having finished all operations.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi it looks like a duck and quaks like a duck. I suspect it is the debug print that is problamatic here. Don't know the implementation though so it is still a guess.